# OpenJMS : Failed to start database 'openjmsdb', see the next exception for details

Tags: java, openjms

Yesterday, I created a topic and a queue on my OpenJMS server, graphically (using `admin.sh`). I was able to start it with `openjms/bin/admin.sh` and then clicking on the menus "Start OpenJMS server>Start connections, etc." and even by executing only `openjms/bin/startupt.sh` (instead of `admin.sh`).

Today, I deleted all the topic and queue (graphically, by right-cliking on "Delete" on each node `Topic` and `Queue` ).

And now, when I type `openjms/bin/startup.sh`, it displays this exception : http://pastebin.com/PY2wpBkv

Do you know why and how to solve this problem ?

NB : the graphical tool (so `admin.sh`) still works well.

Answer (score 0):

In fact one must use the classes from package `org.exolab.jms.administration` (and not use `javax.jms.Session`'s `create<Queue||Topic>` methods). Read this page : http://openjms.sourceforge.net/usersguide/admin.html